# Lambdas: local variables need final, instance variables don't

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, final

In a lambda, local variables need to be final, but instance variables don't. Why so?

Comment: Related: [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544)

Comment: Let be known that at least with the latest version of the compiler java 1.8 local variables only need to be effectively final so they don't need to be declared final per se but the cannot be modified.

Comment: After reading all the answers here, I still think it's just a rule enforced by the compiler, designed to minimize programmer error - that is, there is no technical reason why mutable local variables can't be captured, or why captured local variables can't be mutated, for that matter. This point is supported by the fact that this rule can be readily circumvented by using an object wrapper (so the object reference is effectively final, but not the object itself). Another way is to create an array, i.e. `Integer[] count = {new Integer(5)}`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457016/7154924.

Comment: @McDowell, lambda's are not merely syntax sugar for anonymous classes but a different construct altogether.

Comment: @flow2k this is ok only as long as the reference to "count" doesn't change which is not the same as changing the value that points to it. Reference to the value must be final/effectively final, not the value itself. Considering this and article http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-are-the-reasons-for-the-restriction-to-effective-immutability/ it does make sense why allowing a mutable reference will have undesirable effects.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The fundamental difference between a field and a local variable is that the local variable is ***copied*** when JVM creates a lambda instance. On the other hand, fields can be changed freely, because the changes to them are propagated to the outside class instance as well (their *scope* is the whole outside class, as Boris pointed out below).

The easiest way of thinking about anonymous classes, closures and labmdas is from the *variable scope* perspective; imagine a copy constructor added for all local variables you pass to a closure.

Comment: Right, then the anonymous class constructor doesn't need to copy the instance variable because it can just reference it. Good explanation!

Answer (score 26):

In a document of project lambda, [State of the Lambda v4](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html), under Section **7. Variable capture**, it is mentioned that:

> It is our intent to prohibit capture of mutable local variables. The
> reason is that idioms like this:
>
> ```
> int sum = 0;
> list.forEach(e -> { sum += e.size(); });
> ```
>
> are fundamentally serial; it is quite difficult to write lambda bodies
> like this that do not have race conditions. Unless we are willing to
> enforce—preferably at compile time—that such a function cannot escape
> its capturing thread, this feature may well cause more trouble than it
> solves.

Another thing to note here is, local variables are passed in the constructor of an inner class when you access them inside your inner class, and this won't work with non-final variable because value of non-final variables can be changed after construction.

While in case of an instance variable, the compiler passes a reference of the object and object reference will be used to access instance variables. So, it is not required in case of instance variables.

PS : It is worth mentioning that anonymous classes can access only final local variables (in Java SE 7), while in Java SE 8 you can access effectively final variables also inside lambda as well as inner classes.

Answer (score 20):

In [Java 8 in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/java-8-in-action) book, this situation is explained as:

> You may be asking yourself why local variables have these restrictions. 
>   First, there’s a key
>   difference in how instance and local variables are implemented behind the scenes. Instance
>   variables are stored on the heap, whereas local variables live on the stack. If a lambda could
>   access the local variable directly and the lambda were used in a thread, then the thread using the
>   lambda could try to access the variable after the thread that allocated the variable had
>   deallocated it. Hence, Java implements access to a free local variable as access to a copy of it
>   rather than access to the original variable. This makes no difference if the local variable is
>   assigned to only once—hence the restriction.
>   Second, this restriction also discourages typical imperative programming patterns (which, as we
>   explain in later chapters, prevent easy parallelization) that mutate an outer variable.

Comment: I really think there are some issues in **Java 8 in Action** in this point. If the **local variable** here refers to the variables created in the method but accessed by the lambdas, and the multi-thread is achieved by `ForkJoin`, then there will be a copy for different threads and mutation in lambdas is acceptable theoretically, in which case it can be **mutated**. But the thing here is different, **local variables** used in lambda is for **parallelisation** achieved by `parallelStream`, and these **local variables** are shared by different threads which are based on the **lambdas**.

Comment: So the **first point** is actually not right, there is no **so-called copy**, it's shared among threads in parallelStream. And sharing mutable variables among threads is dangerous just like the **Second point**. That's why we prevent it and introduce built-in methods in Stream to handle these cases.

Answer (score 15):

Because instance variables are always accessed through a field access operation on a reference to some object, i.e. `some_expression.instance_variable`. Even when you don't explicitly access it through dot notation, like `instance_variable`, it is implicitly treated as `this.instance_variable` (or if you're in an inner class accessing an outer class's instance variable, `OuterClass.this.instance_variable`, which is under the hood `this.<hidden reference to outer this>.instance_variable`).

Thus an instance variable is never directly accessed, and the real "variable" you're directly accessing is `this` (which is "effectively final" since it is not assignable), or a variable at the beginning of some other expression.

Comment: Nice explanation for this question

Answer (score 15):

*Putting up some concepts for future visitors:*

Basically it all boils down to the point that **compiler should be able to deterministically tell that lambda expression body is not working on a stale copy of the variables**.

In case of local variables, compiler has no way to be sure that lambda expression body is not working on a stale copy of the variable unless that variable is final or effectively final, so local variables should be either final or effectively final.

Now, in case of instance fields, when you access an instance field inside the lambda expression then compiler will append a `this` to that variable access (if you have not done it explicitly) and since `this` is effectively final so compiler is sure that lambda expression body will always have the latest copy of the variable (please note that multi-threading is out of scope right now for this discussion). So, in case instance fields, compiler can tell that lambda body has latest copy of instance variable so instance variables need not to be final or effectively final.  Please refer below screen shot from an Oracle slide:

[image]

Also, please note that if you are accessing an instance field in lambda expression and that is getting executed in multi-threaded environment then you could potentially run in problem.

Comment: Would you mind providing the source of the Oracle slide?

Comment: @hagrawal could you please elaborate your final statement regarding multi-threaded environment? Is it with respect to actual value of member variable at any time since many threads are running at same time so they can override the instance variable. Also, if I synchronize the member variables properly then also the problem remains?

Comment: best answer for the question I guess ;)

Answer (score 10):

It seems like you are asking about variables that you can reference from a lambda body.

From the [JLS §15.27.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

So you don't need to declare variables as `final` you just need to make sure that they are "effectively final". This is the same rule as applies to anonymous classes.

Comment: Yes, but instance variables can be referenced and assigned in a lambda, which is surprising to me. Only local variables have the `final` limitation.

Comment: @Gerard Because an instance variable has the scope of the whole class. This is exactly the same logic as for an anonymous class - there are plenty of tutorials explaining the logic.

Answer (score 6):

Within Lambda expressions you can use effectively final variables from the surrounding scope.
Effectively means that it is not mandatory to declare variable final but make sure you do not change its state within the lambda expresssion.

You can also use this within closures and using "this" means the enclosing object but not the lambda itself as closures are anonymous functions and they do not have class associated with them.

So when you use any field (let say private Integer i;)from the enclosing class which is not declared final and not effectively final it will still work as the compiler makes the trick on your behalf and insert "this" (this.i).

```
private Integer i = 0;
public  void process(){
    Consumer<Integer> c = (i)-> System.out.println(++this.i);
    c.accept(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a code example, as I didn't expect this either, I expected to be unable to modify anything outside my lambda

```
 public class LambdaNonFinalExample {
    static boolean odd = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       //boolean odd = false; - If declared inside the method then I get the expected "Effectively Final" compile error
       runLambda(() -> odd = true);
       System.out.println("Odd=" + odd);
    }

    public static void runLambda(Callable c) throws Exception {
       c.call();
    }

 }
```

Output:
     Odd=true

Answer (score 4):

YES, you can change the **member variables** of the instance but you **CANNOT** change the instance itself just like when you handle **variables**.

Something like this as mentioned:

```
    class Car {
        public String name;
    }

    public void testLocal() {
        int theLocal = 6;
        Car bmw = new Car();
        bmw.name = "BMW";
        Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).limit(2)
        .forEach(i -> {
//            bmw = new Car(); // LINE - 1;
            bmw.name = "BMW NEW"; // LINE - 2;
            System.out.println("Testing local variables: " + (theLocal + i));

        });
        // have to comment this to ensure it's `effectively final`;
//        theLocal = 2; 
    }
```

The basic principle to restrict the **local variables** is about [data and computation validity](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-are-the-reasons-for-the-restriction-to-effective-immutability/)

> If the lambda, evaluated by the second thread, were given the ability to mutate local variables. Even the ability to read the value of mutable local variables from a different thread would introduce the necessity for **synchronization** or the use of **volatile** in order to avoid reading stale data.

But as we know the [**principal purpose** of the lambdas](http://www.lambdafaq.org/why-are-lambda-expressions-being-added-to-java/)

> Amongst the different reasons for this, the most pressing one for the Java platform is that they make it easier to distribute processing of collections over **multiple threads**.

Quite unlike local variables, local **instance** can be mutated, because it's **shared** globally. We can understand this better via the [heap and stack difference](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory):

> Whenever an object is created, it’s always stored in the Heap space and stack memory contains the reference to it. Stack memory only contains local primitive variables and reference variables to objects in heap space.

So to sum up, there are two points I think really matter:

1. It's really hard to make the **instance** *effectively final*, which might cause lots of senseless burden (just imagine the deep-nested class);
2. the instance itself is already globally shared and lambda is also shareable among threads, so they can work together properly since we know we're handling the **mutation** and want to pass this mutation around;

Balance point here is clear: if you know what you are doing, you can do it **easily** but if not then the **default restriction** will help to avoid *insidious* bugs.

P.S. If the *synchronization* required in **instance mutation**, you can use directly the [stream reduction methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) or if there is dependency issue in **instance mutation**, you still can use `thenApply` or `thenCompose` in [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) while `mapping` or methods similar.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a key difference in how local and instance variables are implemented behind the scenes. Instance variables are stored in the heap, whereas local variables stored in the stack.
If the lambda could access the local variable directly and the lambda was used in a thread, then the thread using the lambda could try to access the variable after the thread that allocated the variable had deallocated it.

In short: to ensure another thread does not override the original value, it is better to provide access to the copy variable rather than the original one.