# Why do java 8 lambdas allow access to non-final class variables?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I understand why the following is not accepted by the compiler:

```
class Foo {
    public Supplier<String> makeSupplier() {
        String str = "hello";
        Supplier<String> supp = () -> return str;

        // gives the expected compile error because
        // str is not effectively final
        // (str is a local variable, compile-time error
        //  as per JLS 15.27.2.)
        str = "world";

        return supp;
    }
}
```

What puzzles me is that the compiler accepts the following, and that the unit test passes:

```
class Bar {
    private String str = "hello";

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public Supplier<String> makeSupplier() {
        Supplier<String> supp = () -> { return str; };
        return supp;
    }

    @Test 
    public void Unit_lambdaCapture() {    
        Supplier<String> supp = makeSupplier();
        Assert.assertEquals(supp.get(), "hello");
        setStr("foo");
        Assert.assertEquals(supp.get(), "foo");
    }
}
```

Why is the above valid and working correctly? Pointers to relevant sections of the JLS are welcome (section 15.27.2. only talks about local variables).

Comment: In your second example you return a new lambda instance with a variable captured from the context, which doesn't change in the process of creating the lambda; `str` is "effectively final", which is why it is accepted. Had you tried and reassign `str` after you had initialized the supplier, you would have a compile error as well.

Comment: As @fge stated in the second example `setStr("foo")` is method-local.

Comment: @fge Seems like a candidate for an answer, rather than a comment?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Not a duplicate, but certainly a relevant link to post.

Comment: @Duncan not really, I don't point to the correct sections of the JLS etc and I unfortunately lack the time to dig around ;)

Comment: I believe that when lambda refers to the instance field, lambda actually captures `this`, not `this.str`. `this` remains unchanged and `this.str` is just an expression which is evaluated when lambda is evaluated.

Comment: Possibly this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055392/lambdas-local-variables-need-final-instance-variables-dont

Comment: @fge I tried what you suggested, but the compiler accepts this:  `public Supplier<String> makeSupplier() {
        Supplier<String> supp = () -> { return str; };
        str = "ff";
        return supp;
    }`

Comment: **DO READ** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850049/4691279

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We all agree that the first example won't work as local variables or parameters must be [final or effectively final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) to be used within a [lambda expression body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2).

But your second example does not involve local variables or parameters, as `str` is an instance field. Lambda expressions can accessing instance fields the same way as instance methods:

*[15.27.2. Lambda Body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)*

> A lambda body is either a single expression or a block (§14.2). Like a method body, a lambda body describes code that will be executed whenever an invocation occurs.

In fact, the java compiler creates a private method `lambda$0` out of your lambda expression, that simply accesses the instance field `str`:

```
private java.lang.String lambda$0() {
    0 aload_0;                /* this */
    1 getfield 14;            /* .str */
    4 areturn;
}
```

**Another point of view:** You could also implement the `Supplier` using a plain-old anonymous inner class:

```
public Supplier<String> makeSupplier() {
    return new Supplier<String>() {
        public String get() { return str; }
    };
}
```

Accessing instance fields from inner classes is very common and not a speciality of Java 8.

Comment: Future visitors - **DO READ** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850049/4691279

Answer (score 0):

It does not. It allows access to effectively final class variables.

> A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Comment: I was almost about to agree. But in that case, the lambda expression is accessing an instance field which is neither a variable nor a parameter.

Comment: Actually, the value accessed is a field. There is nothing that prevents access to non-final *fields*, as you can see in the document you quoted.

Comment: Future visitors - **DO READ** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850049/4691279