# Is there any way to change value captured by Java Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

something like this:

```
    Integer value = 3;
    Consumer<Integer> consumer = input -> {
        value = value * 2;
    };
    consumer.accept(100);
    System.out.println(value);
```

Thanks!
[Solved]

```
    AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(3);
    Consumer<Integer> consumer = input -> {
        value.getAndAdd(5); // 8
        System.out.println(value.get());
    };
    consumer.accept(100);
    System.out.println(value.get()); // 8
```

also thanks for Umer Farooq` s answer
[Modifying local variable from inside lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026824/modifying-local-variable-from-inside-lambda/30026897)

Comment: Are you sure this is Java and not javascript?

Comment: Has been re-edited

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026824/modifying-local-variable-from-inside-lambda/30026897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

[JLS 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) says:

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

Since you use `value` in the lambda, but declare it outside of the lambda, it has to be final or effectively final. That means you can't assign it a value more than once.

Of course, if `value` were a mutable object (an `AtomicInteger`, for instance), then you *would* be able to mutate it. The `value` reference itself would be unchanged, but the object it references would be changed.

Answer (score 0):

So since the Java compiler only allows final or member references to be accessed in a lambda or anonymous inner classes, the answer is no. You can however (as you seem to have found), change the state inside of a final reference.

You found a workaround with `AtomicInteger`, which works in your specific case as you are modifying an `Integer`. Placing your reference in a final single value array will work for everything though. It's not very pretty, but if you are using `IntelliJ` it will offer to do this change for you if you try modifying final state in a situation like this.

Here is an example:

```
final int[] value = { 3 };
Consumer<Integer> consumer = input -> {
    value[0] = value[0] * 2;
};
consumer.accept(100);
System.out.println(value[0]);
```