# How to return multiple values from a transactions?

Tags: jooq

**Is it possible to invoke `DSLContext.transactionResult()` multiple times against the same transaction?**

I'd like to insert rows into different tables within the same transaction and return the primary keys to the enclosing (non-transactional) code block.

I know that I can probably create some custom return type to hold multiple values but from a code readability perspective it would be preferable to invoke `DSLContext.transactionResult()` multiple times and pass by an individual result each time.

Comment: What do you mean by _pass by an individual result each time_?

Comment: @knutwannheden Answered as a comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The callable invoked by `DSLContext.transactionResult()` represents the transaction and is committed or rolled back using the `TransactionProvider` obtained from `Configuration#transactionProvider()` once the transaction finishes.

But transactions can be nested (see examples in [documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/)). So if you have an outer transaction (again using `DSLContext.transactionResult()`), then you could have a nested transaction for each table you want to insert into within that and probably achieve your goal that way.

Comment: I want to pass the inserted row IDs (one per table type) outside the top-most `DSLContext.transactionResult()` block. Nesting transactions would allow me to run the inserts within the same transaction but I cannot pass the values outside of the transaction without playing some tricks (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30026897/14731). Is there a better way?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of Java return type you had in mind here. A simple example would be to use a `Map`, where the table name is the key. That would work very well since there would be no need to reassign the variable. Your nested transactions would simply call `Map#put(Object, Object)` and the outer transaction would then return the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with [Knut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57326596/521799). A simple example for this would be:

```java
// The global transaction
List<Integer> result = outer.transactionResult(inner -> {

    // The transactional logic you wish to repeat:
    TransactionalCallable<List<Integer>> block = ctx -> { ... };

    // Your repeated calls to nested transactions, producing separate generated keys, each
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(inner.transactionResult(block));
    list.addAll(inner.transactionResult(block));
    return list;
});
```