# For loop wait for all CompletableFutures to give result, and add result to int

Tags: java, for-loop, completable-future

I have a method getCount(id) that returns an integer from a database, as a CompletableFuture. I want to loop through all the ids, and get the result for all of them, and add them to one global int. Then I want to do something with that int:

```java
int totalCount;
for (String id : API.getIDs()) {
    //OtherAPI.getCount(id) will return the CompletableFuture<Integer>
    OtherAPI.getCount(id).thenAccept(count -> totalCount += count);
}

System.out.println("" + totalCount);
```

This gives an error, because you can't add an integer to another integer in thenAccept, because it's a consumer. What is the way to do this?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Compiler error? Runtime Exception? Unexpected behaviour? Please [edit] the post and provide the necessary information.

Comment: Added, but I added "won't work" more to make it clear that it can't be done this way.

Comment: You cannot change an outer-scope variable in a lambda since the variable must be final or efectively-final wrt. the lambda. You can use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to avoid this problem.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know how to do it. That is the reason for this question.

Comment: There's a solution for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026824/modifying-local-variable-from-inside-lambda

Comment: @wisnix But with a AtomicInteger, it won't wait for all the iterations, is it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it wait for all the iterations? Also, why are you using `thenAccept` instead of `get`? While `AtomicInteger` will work it is also an overkill.

Comment: Because the code above is an example of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind that the function passed to `thenAccept` can be performed by an arbitrary thread, so *thankfully*, Java does not allow them to modify a local variable. When you change the variable to a field on the heap, the compiler would accept it, but the result would be entirely broken.

The simplest solution would be

```
int totalCount = 0;
for(String id: API.getIDs()) {
    totalCount += OtherAPI.getCount(id).join();
}
```

It just waits for the availability of each value, to sum them locally. Depending on the operations encapsulated by the `OtherAPI.getCount(…)` calls, this might even be the most efficient solution.

But when these operations take a significant time and can truly run in parallel, i.e. do not depend on a shared resource internally, it might be beneficial not to wait before all operations have been commenced.

You can do this like

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0);
for(String id: API.getIDs()) {
    result = result.thenCombine(OtherAPI.getCount(id), Integer::sum);
}
System.out.println(result.join());
```

Here, the loop is entirely wait-free. It will schedule the summing operation, to be done when two operations have been completed. Then, only the `join` call at the end will wait for the final result. At this point, all asynchronous operations have been submitted already.