# Use non-final variable inside inner method using Java

Tags: java

Im using Jdbctemplate and trying to set a boolean value inside the mapRow method. But it doesnt allow,  It says

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable isEveryTransactionNotClosed inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

Here is my code

```
public boolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed (String txIds) throws QiibException {
    String sql = "<Query> ";
    logger.info("isEveryTransactionNotClosed SQL :"+sql);
    boolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed = true;
    try {
        isEveryDealNotClosed =  getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {dealIds}, 
                new RowMapper<Boolean>()  {
                public Boolean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    if (!rs.next()) {
                        isEveryTransactionNotClosed = false;    -->                         
                    }
                }
        });
    } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        logger.error("Empty result data - isEveryTransactionNotClosed ");   
    }
   return isEveryTransactionNotClosed ;
}
```

How can I use isEveryTransactionNotClosed inside class?

Comment: by calling it? can you show how you try to call it now? don't give your variables the same names as your methods. declare your variable as final and try again

Comment: @Stultuske, I'm calling the method as boolean result = isEveryTransactionNotClosed (String dealIds);

Comment: there are some issues in your code. check the answer I just posted, and try again.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029849/why-do-java-8-lambdas-allow-access-to-non-final-class-variables

Comment: You can't access a local variable into an inner class if that local is not final (or since java 8 effectively final)

Comment: A fast way to do it is change the type of your `boolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed` to `final AtomicBoolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed`

Comment: @Alex, can you please explain with the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

```
    public boolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed (String txIds) throws QiibException {
        String sql = "<Query> ";
        logger.info("isEveryTransactionNotClosed SQL :"+sql);
        try {
            final boolean isEveryDealNotClosed =  getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {dealIds}, 
                    new RowMapper<Boolean>()  {
                    public Boolean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        if (!rs.next()) {
                            isEveryTransactionNotClosed = false;    -->                         
                        }
                    }
            });
        } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            logger.error("Empty result data - isEveryTransactionNotClosed ");   
        }
       return isEveryTransactionNotClosed ;
    }
```

would solve the issue you have now, which would give two new issues:

```
 1. You would try to re-assign a final variable
 2. Your method has a return value Boolean, but doesn't return anything.
```

Change your code to:

```
public boolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed (String txIds) throws QiibException {
    String sql = "<Query> ";
    logger.info("isEveryTransactionNotClosed SQL :"+sql);
    boolean isEveryDealNotClosed = true;
    try {
        isEveryDealNotClosed =  getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {dealIds}, 
                new RowMapper<Boolean>()  {
                public Boolean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    return rs.next();
                }
        });
    } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        logger.error("Empty result data - isEveryTransactionNotClosed ");   
    }
   return isEveryDealNotClosed;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Elaborated with reasons too.

Comment: So then the variable names dont match - `isEveryTransactionNotClosed ` vs `isEveryDealNotClosed `

Comment: @GyroGearless yes, just seemed that way on a quick glance

Comment: @Stultuske, you missed one point. isEveryTransactionNotClosed  should be renamed as isEveryDealNotClosed . Please update your code

Comment: @Yakhoob nice catch, will do :)

Comment: @Stultuske, and you should define isEveryDealNotClosed  before try. ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution of [Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46883883/4391450) is correct. But it is not explaining the reason of the error.

The short answer is that you can't use a non-final local variable in an inner-class. It can be effectivly final (so it doesn't really need the keyword).

From the [JLS - 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.

Explaining your problem.

It is **not final** and definitly **not effectivly final** since your inner class alter the local variable.

Another solutions :

- Inner class are allowed to access and modify member variables,
- Use wrapper to create the final instance olding your value

Comment: I think you miss a part in your post: "It is not final and definitly not effectivly final since your inner class the variable" (I assume you mean re-assigns or changes)?

Comment: @Stultuske indeed, didn't review that line... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `AtomicBoolean` in place of boolean if you need a final changeable boolean. See below for the changes on your code.

However, there is some other errors in your code, as stated by others. You may need to change it as well in order to make it work.

```
public boolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed (String txIds) throws QiibException {
    String sql = "<Query> ";
    logger.info("isEveryTransactionNotClosed SQL :"+sql);
    // changed line
    final AtomicBoolean isEveryTransactionNotClosed = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    try {
        isEveryDealNotClosed =  getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {dealIds}, 
                new RowMapper<Boolean>()  {
                public Boolean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    if (!rs.next()) {
                        // changed line
                        isEveryTransactionNotClosed.set(false);                         
                    }
                }
        });
    } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        logger.error("Empty result data - isEveryTransactionNotClosed ");   
    }
   return isEveryTransactionNotClosed.get();
}
```

Comment: but you are still using isEveryDealNotClosed  (inside try, first statement). That should be isEveryTransactionNotClosed , right

Comment: I just copied your code and change the lines to illustrate how to use `AtomicBoolean` in inner class. There are still other errors, like the one stated by others that your method `mapRow` has to return a `Boolean`, has to be changed.