# How does the lambda expression access to class fields?

Tags: java, oop

```
public class ClickButton extends JButton {
   private int clicks = 0;

   public ClickButton() {
    super("0");

    this.addActionListener (e -> {
        ++clicks ;
        this.setText(clicks + "");
        });
   }
}
```

How is the lambda expression, inside of addActionListener method, able to access the "clicks" field of my class? Is this because, I can consider Lambda-Expression as a very short initialisation of an inner class, which can of course access this field?

Comment: Well, `clicks` is `this.clicks` and you obviously have access to `this` in the constructor. If your question is why the operation `++clicks` is possible then check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/67065119/12323248.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be accessible?