# Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I want to implement this endpoint with internal search:

```
@PostMapping("terminals_risk_filter/change_order/{terminalId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateFiltersPositions(@PathVariable Integer terminalId,
            @RequestBody List<ChangeOrderRiskFiltersDTO> newFiltersPositionsList) {

        List<RiskFilters> filterList = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalId(terminalId);

        for (int i = 0; i < newFiltersPositionsList.size(); i++) {
//          RiskFilters filter = filterList.findById(newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getId());

            Optional<RiskFilters> filter_payload = filterList.stream().filter(f -> newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getId() == f.getId()).findAny();
            RiskFilters filter = filter_payload.get();      

            filter.setPosition(newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getPosition());
            riskFilterService.save(filter);
        }
        return ok().build();
    }
```

But I get error message `Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final` Can you give me some advice how I can fix this issue, please? For example can I skip the `for` cycle and use maybe stream into stream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can you give me some advice how I can fix this issue, please?

Why does this happen? You can read about it here: [Lambdas: local variables need final, instance variables don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055392/lambdas-local-variables-need-final-instance-variables-dont)

Minimal changes to solve your problem: Don't use the `i` variable itself. Create a copy of it and make it `final`.

```
final int iCopy = i;
Optional<RiskFilters> filter_payload = filterList.stream().filter(f -> newFiltersPositionsList.get(iCopy).getId() == f.getId()).findAny();
```

> For example can I skip the for cycle and use maybe stream into stream?

You could give it a try:

```
// replace the for-loop

// or just.... `newFiltersPositionsList.forEach(/* ... */)`
newFiltersPositionsList.stream().forEach(filterPosition -> {
    Optional<RiskFilters> filter_payload = filterList.stream()
            .filter(f -> filterPosition.getId() == f.getId())
            .findAny();
    RiskFilters filter = filter_payload.get();

    filter.setPosition(filterPosition.getPosition());
    riskFilterService.save(filter);
});
```

Also, you could use a *for-each* instead of a *for-loop*:

```
for (ChangeOrderRiskFiltersDTO filterPosition : newFiltersPositionsList) {
    Optional<RiskFilters> filter_payload = filterList.stream()
           .filter(f -> filterPosition.getId() == f.getId())
           .findAny();
    RiskFilters filter = filter_payload.get();
    filter.setPosition(filterPosition.getPosition());
    riskFilterService.save(filter);
}
```

Comment: in general is there any better solution?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I added an alternative to your for-loop. There can be many other good combinations to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below as well.

```
final ChangeOrderRiskFiltersDTO dto = newFiltersPositionsList.get(i);
Optional<RiskFilters> filter_payload = filterList.stream().filter(f -> dto.getId() == f.getId()).findAny();
if(filter_payload.isPresent()){
  RiskFilters filter = filter_payload.get();
  //More operations
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the simple solution of adding a final copy of the i, you can extract the actual "final" information:

```
final int id = newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getId()
```

And your lambda can become:

```
f -> id == f.getId()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** an answer to the original question.

The same error message appears if you try to assign a variable in an enclosing class from an inner anonymous class. For example:

```
    int result = 0;
    hibernateSession.doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
            result = 1;
        }
    });
```

In this case, I found a workaround pointing to an array:

```
    int[] result = new int[1];
    hibernateSession.doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
            result[0] = 1;
        }
    });
```