# Method with boolean return type not working inside main()

Tags: java, methods, static

I had static method which is to find out prime number and it is working fine but the same method i am trying to keep inside main method it is throwing errors by stating illegal modifiers for parameter and void method does not return value
the same code is working fine outside of main method, any one plz sugggest me why it is not working in main() . Thanks ..!!

**My method**

```
public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
        if (number == 2 || number == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
        for (int i = 3; i < sqrt; i += 2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Inside main() with lot of error message
[inside main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlTdR.png)

**Solution**

Thanks Logan  --- need to add methods outside main method 
my working code is added below

```
public class Squar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        Squar s = new Squar();
        //System.out.println(s.isPrime(num));
        scan.close();
        System.out.println("M2 "+s.isPrimeNumber(num));


    }
    public  boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
        if (number == 2 || number == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
        for (int i = 3; i < sqrt; i += 2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your attempt to call this.

Comment: Can you include the code where you are calling `isPrimeNumber()`?

Comment: Did you declare this method inside `main`? That's not allowed.

Comment: Let me add full code one moment

Comment: (also, 1 isn't prime).

Comment: public class Squar   this is class name

Comment: As @ernest_k mentioned, you can’t declare a method in another method. The declaration for `isPrimeNumber()` must go outside of `main()`.

Comment: yes ernst it is throwing errors but the same method working outside main

Comment: @user10100235 What issues are you having when you move it outside?

Comment: Yes logan it is working fine now. Thank you all for your time so inside main method we cannot declare any method. have to try outside of main and it should be static i believe ...?

Comment: non static method also accepting from main can able to pass values using object.

Comment: You need to include the code *in the question as text*.

Comment: as i am new not aware of that chrylis i added now. Thanks much. i will add in text format here after thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You can declare any method outside main as same like how you are creating methods usually after class declaration.

Comment: Hi Thanks 1 is not a prime number and i added one more if loop in the beginning of my code thank you @Andy Turner

if(number == 1){
   return false;
  }

Comment: @user10100235  hava a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634328/can-methods-in-java-be-nested-and-what-is-the-effect

Comment: @user10100235 you are wecome bro. if an answer really solves your question mark it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because Java does not support nested function.
You are implementing method inside other method, that is not possible. to nest methods use lambdas in java 8.

have a look at [Can methods in java be nested and what is the effect? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367714/nested-functions-in-java/)