# Java method and boolean methods

Tags: java

I would like help with my java program. I'm trying to compare two different inputs from the user and check if these inputs are between the minimum and maximum age. Also, I need to have two methods in the program and use the boolean method but I got stuck on it. Can someone help me to understand it better and fix it?
What I have so far is:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nome, nomes;
    int ida, idade;
    
    final int MIN_AGE = 18;
    final int MAX_AGE = 65;
    
    Scanner diSexta = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter first person's name:");
    nome = diSexta.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter " + nome + "'s age:");
    ida = diSexta.nextInt();
    diSexta.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter second person's name:");
    nomes = diSexta.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter " + nomes + "'s age:");
    idade = diSexta.nextInt();
   
    public static boolean estado() {
    if (ida >= MIN_AGE || ida <= MAX_AGE && idade >= MIN_AGE || idade <= MAX_AGE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Also, I need to have two methods in the program and use the boolean method but I got stuck on it." - where exactly?

Comment: `a || b && c || d` is same as `a || (b && c) || d`. Also are you sure you need `||`? Note that `||` represents *sum* or ranges, while `&&` represents *intersection*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested functions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367714/nested-functions-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code does not compile. You need to make `MIN_AGE` and `MAX_AGE` constants. You also need to move `estado()` method outside `main()` method. And then you need to review your `estado()` implementation. It seems you are looking for something along the following lines:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static final int MIN_AGE = 18;
    static final int MAX_AGE = 65;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nome, nomes;
        int ida, idade;

        Scanner diSexta = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter first person's name:");
        nome = diSexta.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter " + nome + "'s age:");
        ida = diSexta.nextInt();
        diSexta.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter second person's name:");
        nomes = diSexta.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter " + nomes + "'s age:");
        idade = diSexta.nextInt();
        System.out.print(estado(ida, idade));
    }

    public static boolean estado(int ida, int idade) {
        return ida >= MIN_AGE && ida <= MAX_AGE && idade >= MIN_AGE && idade <= MAX_AGE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Also, to substitute the print true that shows and use a if statement answering if (true)
     System.out.print ("Both are between 18 and 65") and for false Neither are between 18 and 65")

Answer (score 0):

Logic error in `if` statement: All conditions must be evaluated with `&&`. Because the method returns true when `ida` variable is greater than `MIN_AGE` and `MAX_AGE`. The same applies to the control of the `idade` variable.

```java
public static boolean estado() 
{
    if((ida >= MIN_AGE && ida <= MAX_AGE) && (idade >= MIN_AGE && idade <= MAX_AGE))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```