# Nested Java methods

Tags: java, methods

Earlier in my code I call the method

```
public static boolean divides(int num, int denom)
{
    if (num%denom==0)
       return true;
    else return false; 
}
```

Later I am calling the method

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)

I want to call divides in isLeapYear. Do I have to define divides all over again? Right now I have

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{
public static boolean divides(int num, int denom)
{
   if (divides.class == true && (year%400 ==0) || ((year%4==0) 
       && (year%100 !=0)));
       return true;
       else return false;
}
```

}

And I get the error that divides is already defined, but when I don't put the whole public static etc. statement in there it wonders what divides is.

I'm also getting a host of other errors (such as it not being able to find year's type after I nest divides), but that's not the main one.

Comment: Methods cannot be nested in Java.

Comment: Object Orientation... [Edit] Nvm, but how about just calling divides instead of redefining it?

Comment: java doesn't allow to use nested method declaration

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634328/can-methods-in-java-be-nested-and-what-is-the-effect

Comment: Simply can be recreated using a new `Class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot nest method declarations.  However, you can simply define them separately and call one from the other.  That is the purpose of functions.

```
public static boolean divides(int num, int denom)
{
    if (num%denom==0)
       return true;
    else return false; 
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{
    return divided(x, y);  // not sure what you are trying to divide, but fill in x and y.
}
```

Comment: I guess he wants `return divided(year, 4) && (!divided(year, 100) || divided(year, 400))`

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot have nested methods in java. what you could do is make a call to `divide()` from your `isLeapYear()` method, passing the respective arguments to it.

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{
divides(1, 2);
return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by passing the respective arguments?

Comment: can the downvoter explain ??, am i missing somethign here ??

Comment: @PermGenError I find your answer lacking feels for the OP, it's obvious that he doesn't know what he is doing and your answer would still be hard for him to understand.

Comment: @Goodwine so, you just downvote it ??, you seem to be new to SO. it doesn't work like that here. you only get to d/v if the answer is wrong.

Comment: @PermGenError when I hover, it says "This answer is not useful", and that's how I felt.

Answer (score 1):

First you cannot declare nested methods.

Anyways you don't need to declare divides again.. If it's defined as `static` try to call it `ContainingClass.divides(x,y);`

And what's that `divide.class` thing?

Answer (score 1):

i think you just want to call your method ...

```
public static boolean divides(int num, int denom)
{
    return (num % denom == 0); 
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{
   return (divides(year, 4) && (!divides(year, 100) || divides(year, 400));
}
```

if the code in your if-else-statements simply return the result of your condition you can shorten your code a bit by returning the condition directly

Comment: wouldn't inverting the order of `divides(year, 400) || !divides(year, 100)` to `!divides(year, 100) || divides(year, 400)` make it faster?

Comment: @Goodwine right. since ´!divides(year, 100)` will be true more often than `divides(year, 400)` chances will be higher that `divedes` is only called twice. I'll edit that.

Comment: now you have `!divides(year, 400)` ;) (the `!`)

Comment: *sigh* corrected that. thx. TGIF...