# What are nested classes used for?

Tags: java

What is the purpose of nested classes?
Any examples?
I don't really see the need for them. Why not just create a new class? It seems really unorganized when using a nested class.

Comment: Take a look at [Nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Why do you think its unorganized?

Comment: Putting things that are only used from a single file (and nowhere else) right into that file seems like a good way to organize things, actually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In java what are nested classes and what do they do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634239/in-java-what-are-nested-classes-and-what-do-they-do)

Comment: @Sajit Kinnumkal It just seems to make everything too bunched together with no breathing space. I always see classes as separate from one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Why Use Nested Classes?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

There are several compelling reasons for using nested classes, among them:

- It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place.
- It increases encapsulation.
- Nested classes can lead to more readable and maintainable code.

Logical grouping of classes—If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.

Increased encapsulation—Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.

More readable, maintainable code—Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.

Comment: Similar reasons to why lambda functions were so joyously welcomed by C++ programmers in the new standard.  Sometimes you just want to do something simple and local.

Comment: Thanks :D. I read this on the Really Big Index but was still kind of hesitant.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place.
2. It increases encapsulation.
3. Nested classes can lead to more readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

Uses for nested classes:

- eliminate namespace pollution
- provide the nested class access to private members of the outer class
- organize related code together
- hide implementations of interfaces from the outside world

There are probably other uses, but these, off the top of my head, should be enough to suggest that there might, actually, be a use for them.